# How to set equal heights between flex rows

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm struggling with making equal heights of flex-direction: column layout.
The problem is that I am trying to make a table that contains columns in which located are multiple rows. Having it done, I found out that the rows do not have equal height between flexbox columns.

The question is how to make them equal between columns (eq. 1st row in 1st column equals 1st row in 2nd column - height)?

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  box-sizing:border-box
}

#container .col {
    display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

#container .col .row {
    display: flex;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="row">asdf asdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdf</div>
    <div class="row">asdf</div>
    <div class="row">asdf</div>
    <div class="row">asdf</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="row">asdf</div>
    <div class="row">asdf</div>
    <div class="row">asdf</div>
    <div class="row">asdf</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    while using flex direction column there wont be any direct relation between 2 columns so height will be different Instead you can try the above answer or you can do something like this.
    
     
                   
        <div id="container">
  
  <div class="col">
    <div class="row">asdf asdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdf</div>
    <div class="row">asdf</div>
    <div class="row">asdf</div>
    <div class="row">asdf</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col">
    <div class="row">asdf</div>
    <div class="row">asdf</div>
    <div class="row">asdf</div>
    <div class="row">asdf</div>
  </div>
</div>

     
        #container {
          display: flex;
          box-sizing:border-box;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
        }
        
        #container .col {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: row;
          flex: 0 0 100%;
          
        }
        
        #container .col .row {
            display: flex;
          background: #eee;
          border: 1px solid #ddd;
          flex: 1 1 100%;
        }
    
    
        
       



I the code snippet do not work try opening [this][1]


  [1]: https://codepen.io/sam-123/pen/ExmGpWW
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with css grid:

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  box-sizing:border-box
}

#container .col {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
}

#container .col .row {
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="row">asdf asdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdf</div>
    <div class="row">asdf</div>
    <div class="row">asdf</div>
    <div class="row">asdf</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="row">asdf</div>
    <div class="row">asdf</div>
    <div class="row">asdf</div>
    <div class="row">asdf</div>
  </div>
</div>
```